# What is the wrong with the script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My script is throwing an error in Bash:

```
/tmp/hudson6482258714933636361.sh: line 7: ((: i <=  : syntax error:operand expected (error token is "<=  ")
cp: cannot stat 

‘/var/jenkins_home/jobs/Latha/jobs/ShirePoc/jobs/RetrieveJob/workspace/Deploy/retrieveUnpackaged/*’: No such file or directory
```

Here is the script:

```
COUNT= $(ls -1 | wc -l)
echo $COUNT
for (( i=1 ; i <= $COUNT ; i++ ));
do
  var=package$i.xml
  echo "FILENAME is $var"
  mv -f $var package.xml
  mkdir ${WORKSPACE}/Deploy/unpackaged
  cp -R ${WORKSPACE}/tools/Package/package.xml ${WORKSPACE}/Deploy/unpackaged/
  cd ${WORKSPACE}/Deploy/unpackaged 
  cat package.xml
  ls -ltra
  cd ${WORKSPACE}/Deploy/
  ls -ltr
  ant -buildfile build.xml RetrieveComponent
done
```

Why is the script causing an error?

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe culprit is your `COUNT` variable change it to as follows:

```
COUNT=$(ls -1 | wc -l)
```

Seems like you have space between `=` and `$`. Kindly check and let us know how it goes then.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to [RavinderSingh13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5866580/ravindersingh13) answer, also update all your variables calling as :

```
$i -----> ${i}
```

Doing this will help the kernel to understand the variable names clearly and it will interpolate the names.

Comment: The kernel doesn't interpret the script, the shell does; and the braces are not necessary or useful for solving the OP's problem.